# Can't get data from dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fiddling around with js / jquery .. I'm trying to create a preview based on data entered in a form. In one of the input fields a script adds new fields every time you press Tab (or in other words choose the next field). So from these dynamic fields I want to retrieve data from the first two fields and put them into the preview. What I've done is to run a function that adds a number on the end of the id to those fields, so they get the names contestant_1, contestant_2 etc. based on the number of fields that are opened.
I then want the data from contestant_1 and _2 to be entered in boxes in the preview.
 
What I then made is another function waiting for a keyup event of one of these input fields. BUT it is not able to react to them after they have gained _1 and _2. If I hard code in the first field named _1, then it comes up in the preview.
In the pictures you can see that I have entered Boks1 and Boks2 (Box1 and 2 i Norewegian) in the first two fields, but only Boks1 comes up.

Form
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGrwh.jpg

Preview
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IyX8.jpg

This code is executed when something happens in the field

```
$('#tname').keyup(update_tname);
$('#contestant_1').keyup(update_contestant_1);
$('#contestant_2').keyup(update_contestant_2);
```

This is the function that updates are well only the last two that have some importance on exactly this.

```js
function update_contestant_1(){
  console.log("Inne i update_contestant_1");
  $('#preview').slideDown();
  $('#pview_contestant_1').fadeIn();
 // Values to preview
  var contestant_1 = $('#contestant_1').val();
  $('#display_contestant_1').html(contestant_1);
        }
```

Input field looks like this

```html
<lable for="contestant" class="col-md-2 control-label">Contestants:</lable>
<div class="input-group input-group-option col-md-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="contestant_" name="option[]"  placeholder="Write contestant here..." required></input>
<span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

And this is the function that creates new fields, change id and delete them

```js
$(function () {
  // Variable for counting how many contestants fields that are open
  var i=0;
    $(document).on('focus', 'div.form-group-options div.input-group-option:last-child input', function () {
        var sInputGroupHtml = $(this).parent().html();
// Uncomment comments below to inherit div classes from div on index page.
// This is not in use now, because we need a offset to line input fields below each other
        // var sInputGroupClasses = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        // $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="' + sInputGroupClasses + '">' + sInputGroupHtml + '</div>');
        $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="input-group input-group-option col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">' + sInputGroupHtml + '</div>');
        // Adds a number at the end of the ID
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        var newID='contestant_'+i;
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'div.form-group-options .input-group-addon-remove', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        // Counts down so the next contestants field that opens, has the right number
        i--;
        console.log(i);
        var newID='contestant_'+i;
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
    });

});
```

I will be greatfull for any help.

Also, hope I did this right, this is my first post here.

Comment: So after you create a new input field the keyup event handler doesn't work?

Comment: Not really, it does only work if I hard code the id. I have used Inspect element in Chrome, and I can see that they get the right id

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do. Anyway, after you append the new input do you bind a new event handler? I mean if you say $('something').keypress(...); and 'something' doesn't exist yet then it has no meaning. You have to bind the event handler right after append.

Comment: That sounds like my problem, i want something to happend to two divs: contestant_1 and contestant_2, but they aren't there when the page loades, because the user haven't clicked on the inputfield. So my problem is maybe: how to make js script understand that the id it is looking for, now exists, since it is not there when the page loads